# Removing a link from an html element using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The company I am working for handed me over a messy website ran using templates, so some elements in the website are automatically generated and are active links.

**My main problem** is that there are some elements on the site are active links that aren't suppose to be links at all. I was wondering if there is a way to remove the link from an html element using JQuery and maybe CSS?

this will help me tremendously, thanks in advance. I need to remove all href's from class 'slider'.

Here is some of my jquery, can someone please show me how to add it?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#productsLink").hover(function(){
            $("#productsMenu").slideDown();
        });
        $("#productsLink, #productsMenu").hover(function(){
            $("#productsLink").css("color","red");
        });
        $(".spacer", this).hover(function(){
            $("#productsLink").css('color', 'white');
            $("#productsMenu").slideUp();
            $("#aboutLink").css('color', 'white');
            $("#aboutMenu").slideUp();
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: can you show some code/sample HTML? before anyone gets downvoted due to assumption

Comment: This is a perfect example of what I am dealing with... (need to remove the link) <a href="http"//www.foobar.com"><div>HELLO</div></a>

Comment: is this HTML in an isolated container? or is it all over the page? do they all come in the same url?

Comment: Yes isolated containers, all over the page, all with the same url...

Comment: can you post all of the related HTML, preferrably at least 2 of these containers. we can't pinpoint how to pick out these links apart from the normal links you want retained unless we see some structure.

Comment: <a href="http"//www.foobar.com"><div class='slider'>HELLO</div></a> ..... it is identical to this just with different links... exact same class name and structure, and 3 of them on on the page... I just need to keep the div and disable the link.

Comment: Oh, that's really bad. The HTML code is broken. You can't have a `div` tag inside an `a` tag, the browser will rearrange the code, so the elements won't end up like that in the page. As different browsers handle this in different ways, there is no reliable way to tell how the elements will end up, so there is no reliable way to remove the links.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove links with the class name `slider` from the DOM:

```
$('a.slider').remove();
```

Comment: Do you have _any_ way of differentiating the links you want deleted from the ones you want kept? You can't just delete all `:active` links because it'll remove your authorized ones when you click on them. Do the old ones have a particular class name or ID or title? Or they located in common elements?

Comment: The old one has a class name of 'slider' I would like to disable all links associated with class name 'slider'.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove all `href` attributes from links with class `slider` with this code:

`$('a.slider').removeAttr('href')`

This will keep the content of the elements intact and just disables them as a link.

Answer (score 1):

try unwrapping the sliders using [`.unwrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/), assuming all these links have the class `slider` and they are directly wrapped in an anchor tag.

```
$('.slider').unwrap()
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS is no help here, it could only be used to hide elements completely.

You can use the `replaceWith` method to turn specific `a` elements into `span` elements. Example:

```
$('a.something, a.someother').replaceWith(function(){
  return $('<span/>').text($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: Depending on the case `.unwrap('a')` might also be useful.